# Error while trying to append data to columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, reverse-geocoding

I am trying to reverse geocode data and for that I have below query

```
import overpy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("/home/runner/sample.csv")
df.sort_values(by=['cvdt35_timestamp_s'],inplace=True)

api= overpy.Overpass()
box = 0.0005
queries = []
results = []
df['Name']=''
df['Highway'] =''

with open("sample.csv") as f:
  for row in df.index:
    query = 'way('+str(df.gps_lat_dd.iloc[row]-box)+','+str(df.gps_lon_dd.iloc[row]-box)+','+str(df.gps_lat_dd.iloc[row]+box)+','+str(df.gps_lon_dd.iloc[row]+box)+') ["highway"]; (._;>;); out body;'
    queries.append(query)
  for query in queries :
    result = api.query(query)
    results.append(result)
  for result in results:
    for way in result.ways:
        name = way.tags.get("name", "n/a")
        df['Name'].append(name)
    for way in result.ways:  
        df['Highway']= way.tags.get("highway", "n/a")
```

I am trying to append each result to new column in the data frame but the above code is throwing error.

I tried using

```
for way in result.ways:
        df['Name'] = way.tags.get("name", "n/a")
```

it's giving me all the rows as 'Westland Avenue' where as result should be as follows

```
Brookville Road
Brookville Road
Brookville Road
Brookville Road
Brookville Road
Brookville Road
Brookville Road
Brookville Road
Brookville Road
Brookville Road
Westland Avenue
```

Can anybody help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code on some sample data and got this error while doing so:

> TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'int'>"; only
>   pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid

[`Series.append()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.append.html) only accepts `Series` objects.

Try `df['Name'].append(pd.Series(name))` instead.

Or better yet, create a list of these names, convert the list to a `Series` and then append it.

Comment: Please upvote and accept the answer so the question can be closed.